# Need an efficient and correct way to clear a bit you aren't sure is 1 or 0 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a bitstring, I need to ensure a given bit is 0 but I don't know in advance whether it's a 1 or 0. Is there a way to just tell Javascript, this bit is zero, no matter what it was before?

Comment: When you say "bitstring", do you mean an actual string like `'00101110'`, or something else?

Comment: Yes, of course it is just a number that can be depicted as binary, decimal or hex, and I am using bitwise operators to set bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you hint in your tags, you can use bitwise operators

if n = index of your bit and b = your bit string

then
`b & ~(1 << n)`
will always have the nth bit as 0

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a simple answer ... I'm kind of embarrassed not to have thought of it, but it's been a long day. :)